# Why is ggplot graphing null percentage data points?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've created a test data set to reproduce this problem:

```
Date    Percent
2012-01 3.00%
2012-02 43.00%
2012-03 54.00%
2012-04 43.00%
2012-05 43.00%
2012-06 23.00%
2012-07 12.00%
2012-08 
2012-09 
2012-10 
2012-11 
2012-12
```

These percentages were created by inputting decimal values in a csv file and converting the format of the `Percent` column into Percentage via Microsoft Excel.

When I try to graph this dataset with `ggplot`

```
data <- read.csv("GCdataViz/test2.csv")
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=Date, y=Percent, group=1)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3) 
p
```

I get this graph

[image]

As you can see the null values are plotted, and the Y axis is also odd... The 3% datapoint is plotted above the 23%. It seems `ggplot` doesn't do too well with standardizing axes with percentages. is there a way I can set the correct range for the Y axis assuming I DO NOT KNOW the percentage values (assuming I am abstracted to the actual dataset other than it is a Percent column).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The column `Percent` is a factor. By default, factor labels are orderer alphabetically. Hence, `3.00%` comes after `12.00%`. It will work if you transform the values of `Percent` to numeric values:

The data:

```
data <- read.table(text = "Date    Percent
2012-01 3.00%
2012-02 43.00%
2012-03 54.00%
2012-04 43.00%
2012-05 43.00%
2012-06 23.00%
2012-07 12.00%
2012-08 
2012-09 
2012-10 
2012-11 
2012-12 ", header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

Create a new variable, `Percent2`, with numeric values:

```
data <- transform(data,
                  Percent2 = replace(as.numeric(gsub("%", "", Percent)),
                                     Percent == "", 0))

#       Date Percent Percent2
# 1  2012-01   3.00%        3
# 2  2012-02  43.00%       43
# 3  2012-03  54.00%       54
# 4  2012-04  43.00%       43
# 5  2012-05  43.00%       43
# 6  2012-06  23.00%       23
# 7  2012-07  12.00%       12
# 8  2012-08                0
# 9  2012-09                0
# 10 2012-10                0
# 11 2012-11                0
# 12 2012-12                0
```

Plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x = Date, y = Percent2)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway to check if a column is a percent? They way my program works the user chooses his x and y axis and the plot modifies according to his choice. So in my code I don't know if he'll pick the percent column or another column. If I can check whether a column is a percent, then I can use the replace() method. I realize I did not specify this in the original post.

Comment: @user2649452 What is the structure of the other column the user can choose?

Comment: The other columns will be numeric, or there could be multiple percent columns.

Comment: @user2649452 If the column is numeric, you don't need to modify it.

Comment: But let's say I have 3 columns, Date, Percent, and some numeric column. I only want to modify the Percent column, not the Date column, which is also non-numeric. Is there any conditional I can write that would allow me to check if a column was percentage, then modify it? Again, this is assuming the user chooses which columns to graph, so I won't know the exact structure of the data set.

Comment: @user2649452 You can use `as.numeric(x)`, where `x` is your column. It returns `TRUE` or numeric columns and `FALSE` for factors (percentages). You could also use `if.factor(x)`. For example: `if (is.factor(x)) ...`.

Comment: @user2649452 If it is more complicated, you should create y new question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go ahead and try that.

Answer (score 2):

Sven's answer gets OP most of the way home, but I believe OP does not want any points at all plotted for the values that were blank in the original Excel sheet. This can be accomplished one of two ways:

- Use Sven's solution, followed by `data$Percent2[data$Percent2==0] <- NA`. (This will fail if you have real percent values that are equal to zero, as well as blank values.)
- **Better, in my opinion**: When you save the original Excel sheet as a .csv file, make sure the Percentage column is formatted as `Number` (i.e., `Format -> Cells` and choose `Number`.) Make sure to include as many decimal places as are useful, since the exported text file will only have as many decimal places as you see on screen. For instance, a cell with value `=1/3` will be exported as `0.3` if you only display one decimal place. Obviously you'll need to multiply by 100 in order to have R display percentage values rather than decimal fractions. **R will import the blank spaces as `NA`, and you won't have to do any further processing.**

Comment: Oh I see, basically the csv file will have a numerical value (0.3) and when I import the file, I can multiply every row in that column by 100 (with ddply), so ggplot will order it as numeric, correct? that means I can completely sidestep creating a factor.

Comment: The only problem with this is that I do not know what column the user will pick as the Y axis (he could pick a Percent column or another normal numeric column). So I'm afraid this would not work for me. I realize I didn't specify that I wouldn't know which column the user would pick.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your underlying problem. Who is the user (not you?) & at what point in the workflow are they involved?