# Is there a way to check if a column is a Date in R?

Tags: r

This is a pseudo followup to this question: [Why is ggplot graphing null percentage data points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169762/why-is-ggplot-graphing-null-percentage-data-points)

Let's say this is my dataset:

```
Date        AE      AA      AEF     Percent
1/1/2012    1211    1000    3556    0.03
1/2/2012    100     2000    3221    0.43
1/3/2012    3423    10000   2343    0.54
1/4/2012    10000   3000    332     0.43
1/5/2012    2342    500     4435    0.43
1/6/2012    2342    800     2342    0.23
1/7/2012    2342    1500    1231    0.12
1/8/2012    111     2300    333 
1/9/2012    1231    1313    3433    
1/10/2012   3453    5654    222 
1/11/2012   3453    3453    454 
1/12/2012   5654    7685    3452 

> str(data)
'data.frame':   12 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Date   : Factor w/ 12 levels "10/11/2012","10/12/2012",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ AE     : int  1211 100 3423 10000 2342 2342 2342 111 1231 3453 ...
 $ AA     : int  1000 2000 10000 3000 500 800 1500 2300 1313 5654 ...
 $ AEF    : int  3556 3221 2343 332 4435 2342 1231 333 3433 222 ...
 $ Percent: num  0.03 0.43 0.54 0.43 0.43 0.23 0.12 NA NA NA ...
```

I need something to tell that the 'Date' column is a Date type as opposed to a numeric or character type (this is because I have to convert the 'Date' column of the data input into an actual Date with as.Date(), ASSSUMING that I do not know the column names of the data set).

```
is.numeric(data[[1]]) returns False
is.character(data[[1]]) returns False
```

I made the 'Date' column in Excel, formatting the column in the 'Date' format, then saved the file as a csv. What type is this in R? I seek an expression similar to the above that returns TRUE.

Comment: Do `str(data_set)` and add it to your question.

Comment: `inherits(data[[1]], "Date")`

Comment: @Bryan Good idea, I see that 'Date' is a factor, and is.numeric(data[[1]]) returns TRUE. But if I had multiple factors in the table, is there any way to distinguish the Date?

Comment: @baptiste: it seems that expression returns FALSE for me. I am not familiar with inherit() however.

Comment: Thanks Excel, eh?  When you read in the csv, be sure to do `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` but that won't completely fix your problem, that will read it in as character and you'll still need a conversion.  If you are going to be using dates a lot I recommend the `lubridate` package.

Comment: Ah, yikes, you may not know which column is the date?  Will it be the only one that is character?  That might be the trick.

Comment: There can be more characters. I'm thinking maybe just is.factor() would do the trick? What does stringAsFactors = FALSE do exactly?

Comment: `stringsAsFactors` is an argument of `read.csv` and determines how strings are processed: factors vs characters.  So you are saying that you need to read a csv but the date could be any column and it could be called anything?  Would `names(data_set)` be of any help?

Comment: Hmmm, I don't see how names(data_set) would be of much help because I couldn't actually see the results, it would only be useful to index (in my program). I think I'll go along with your is.character() trick.

Comment: @user2649452 - I don't understand, I've given you a workable answer below that exactly returns what you want.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could try to coerce all the columns to `as.Date` and see which ones succeed. You would need to specify the format you expect dates to be in though. E.g.:

```
data <- data.frame(
  Date=c("10/11/2012","10/12/2012"),
  AE=c(1211,100),
  Percent=c(0.03,0.43)
)

sapply(data, function(x) !all(is.na(as.Date(as.character(x),format="%d/%m/%Y"))))
#Date      AE Percent 
#TRUE   FALSE   FALSE
```

Comment: This is the most accurate thing I have come across. Can you explain how you did it though? I can't seem to find any info on '!all' and is.na.

Comment: Regarding `is.na` and `all`, try looking at this: `?is.na; x <- c(1,2,3,NA,5); is.na(x); ?all; y <- c(1,2,3,4,5); all(y > 0); !all(y > 0); !all(y > 3);`

Comment: @erosennin - did you match the format= argument to the format of your dates?

Comment: no, I have so many columns, but I see now that you specified that we have to know the format. that is too bad.

Comment: This is NOT answering the question. The OP said 'I need something to tell that the 'Date' column is a Date type'. So a simple but reliable check is needed, **not** a transformation to see if it works, since we can assume the column is already a Date type. But HOW do we test THAT? Please scroll down.

Answer (score 41):

Use `inherits` to detect if argument has datatype `Date`:

```
is.date <- function(x) inherits(x, 'Date')

sapply(list(as.Date('2000-01-01'), 123, 'ABC'), is.date)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

If you want to check if character argument can be converted to `Date` then use this:

```
is.convertible.to.date <- function(x) !is.na(as.Date(as.character(x), tz = 'UTC', format = '%Y-%m-%d'))

sapply(list('2000-01-01', 123, 'ABC'), is.convertible.to.date)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: This assumes you've already figured out which columns are Dates already, and converted them properly. It returns `FALSE` for all 3 columns of my test data set.

Comment: You're also missing  the `POSIXct` class, a valid date class in R that comes without an additional `Date` class.

Answer (score 21):

I know this question is old, but I did want to mention that there is now a function in the `lubridate` package for `is.Date` and also `is.POSIXt`

```
sapply(list(as.Date('2000-01-01'), 123, 'ABC'), is.Date)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Shouldn't an NA return NA rather than FALSE? Other tests preserve NA as NA... ```sapply(list(as.Date('2000-01-01'), 123, 'ABC', NA), is.Date)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE```

Answer (score 7):

The OP clearly asks for just a check:

> I need something to tell that the 'Date' column is a Date type

So how many date classes come with R? Exactly two: `Date` and `POSIXt` (**excluding** their derivatives like `POSIXct` and `POSIXlt`).

So we can just check on that, and make it more robust than the answers already given:

```
is.Date <- function(x) {
  inherits(x, c("Date", "POSIXt"))
}
```

As robust as it gets.

```
is.Date(as.Date("2020-02-02"))
#> [1] TRUE
is.Date(as.POSIXct("2020-02-02"))
#> [1] TRUE
is.Date(as.POSIXlt("2020-02-02"))
#> [1] TRUE
```

If you want to know if a column would be successfully *tranformable/coercible* to a Date type, then that's another question. This is as requested for: 'to tell that [...] is a Date type'.

Comment: It works well IF the input is a date. Have you tried `is.Date(as.Date("blablabla"))`? The expected output should be FALSE not error.

Comment: Disagree, the error comes from `as.Date()`, not from `is.Date()`. This function is as solid as it gets for checking indeed IF the input is a date. Exactly like the OP asked.

Comment: Then maby you should change function name to say `is.typeof.Date()` to avoid confusion.

Comment: Disagree, that’s also not the case with `is.numeric()`, `is.logical()`, `is.data.frame()`, etc. The `is.*()` functions are just for checking an S3 class, which my `is.Date()` does as well :)

Comment: Disagree, the is.* functions are to provide a straight answer in automated processing. Is an error an acceptable answer in automated processing? Think about a general goal of this all. Are the errors within your goals?

Comment: Again, my function does not return an error. Your code `as.Date("blablabla")` returns an error.

Comment: So, how can I distinguish date and not-date with your function getting no error?

Comment: Totally different question, but okay: use `try()` or `tryCatch()` if you must.

Answer (score 4):

To work with dates I use a function to identify if the strings are dates, and if they are, convert them to a predefined format (in this case I choose ''%d/%m/%Y'):

```
standarDates <- function(string) {
  patterns = c('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]','[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]','[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]')
  formatdates = c('%Y/%m/%d','%d/%m/%Y','%Y-%m-%d')
  standardformat='%d/%m/%Y'
  for(i in 1:3){
    if(grepl(patterns[i], string)){
      aux=as.Date(string,format=formatdates[i])
      if(!is.na(aux)){
        return(format(aux, standardformat))
      }
    }
  }
  return(FALSE)
}
```

Suppose you have the vector

```
a=c("2018-24-16","1587/03/16","fhjfmk","9885/04/16")

> sapply(a,standarDates)
2018-24-16   1587/03/16       fhjfmk   9885/04/16 
  "FALSE"   "16/03/1587"      "FALSE" "16/04/9885"
```

with the command

```
"FALSE"%in%sapply(a,standarDates)
[1] True
```

you can figure out if all the elements are dates.

The advantage of this function is that you can add more patterns and date formats according to the data with you are working and end with a standard format also for all those dates. (The disadvantage is that it isn't exactly what the question is asking)

I hope this helps

Comment: This was useful for me in 2022, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Function that i created based on answers here, and using now

```
is.Date <- function(date) {
  if (sapply(date, function(x)
     ! all(is.na(as.Date(
     as.character(x),
     format = c("%d/%m/%Y", "%d-%m-%Y", "%Y/%m/%d", "%Y-%m-%d")
     ))))) {
    return(TRUE)
  } else{
    return(FALSE)
  }
}
```

Comment: can you also provide some examples to see how this function works? perhaps throw some strings in the function to see what is happening. When you do let me know to upvote you

Comment: will be good to give some examples and if some warnings come

Answer (score 2):

I will refer to a simple example and I hope it can be generalized.
Say that you have a date

```
d1<-Sys.Date()
d1
```

> "2020-02-12"

```
deparse(d1)
```

> "structure(18304, class = \"Date\")"

Thus

```
grep("Date",deparse(d1))>=1
```

> TRUE

alternatively use

```
class(d1)
```

> "Date"

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question and that I am not providing a self-developed answer, but perhaps some non-experts in R (like myself) could find useful to use the skim function (of the skimr package) to check whether one or more variables of a data frame (df) are in the Date format.

The syntax is just: skim (df) or skimr::skim(df), if one does not want to load the package for just doing this check.

The obtained output is a very detailed summary of the data frame in which variables are grouped by format (character, Date, numeric...) and additional info is provided (e.g. whether there are missing values, descriptive statistics, etc).

Answer (score -1):

This is my way of doing it. Works most of the time but needs improvement

```
MissLt <- function(x, ratio = 0.5){
  sum(is.na(x))/length(x) < ratio
}


IS.Date  <- function(x, addformat = NULL, exactformat = NULL){
  if (is.null(exactformat)){
    format = c("%m/%d/%Y", "%m-%d-%Y","%Y/%m/%d" ,"%Y-%m-%d", addformat) 
    y <- as.Date(as.character(x),format= format)
    MissLt(y,ratio = 1-(1/length(y)))}
  else{
    y <- as.Date(as.character(x),format= exactformat)
    MissLt(y,ratio = 1-(1/length(y)))}
}
sapply(data, IS.Date)
```

Comment: another package that can be considered is called "anytime"

Comment: This is a solution for checking if a column would be successfully tranformable/coercible to a Date type, which was not the question.

Comment: it is basically the same as thelatemail's answer, I just added more formats ...

Comment: And that's great! It is nice code. But it is the answer to another question, such as 'how can I try different formats for creating valid Date types in R?'. The question asked was 'I need something to tell that the 'Date' column is a Date type', so merely a check was requested. Nice suggestion of yours though, keep up the good work!