# r recognizing time columns from integer and float columns

Tags: r, time

I have multiple columns with integer and float data in them. I want to recognize which of those columns have date and time data. For example a column with values like 2,3 are not time data but a column with values like "1959-12-31 17:00:02 MST" has date and time values. How can I do this in a robust way?

I initially thought about using as.POSIXct() function. But I realized that as.POSIXct(2, origin = "1960-01-01")  converts 2 into time and it makes recognizing time values difficult :(

```
> z=2
> as.POSIXct(z, origin = "1960-01-01")  
[1] "1959-12-31 17:00:02 MST"
> z1 <- Sys.time()
> z1
[1] "2014-12-01 19:08:21 MST"
> class(z1)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
> unclass(z) 
[1] 2
> unclass(z1) 
[1] 1417486102
> z1
[1] "2014-12-01 19:08:21 MST"
> as.POSIXct(z, origin = "1960-01-01")
[1] "1959-12-31 17:00:02 MST"
```

Comment: Is this of any assistance?: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18178539/496803

Comment: it is definitely a better idea and thanks for it. But then all the dates have to be in the same format i.e. 11/11/11 or 11-11-11...i wont be able to have multiple formats or some unknown date formats :( Is there any other way

Comment: try `lubridate::parse_date_time` ?