# Insert rows before and after condition into a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have data like this:

```
df <- data.frame(V1=c("stuff", "2nd June 2018", "otherstuff1", "baseball","", "142", "otherstuff2", "football","", "150", "4th June 2018", "otherstuff99", "hockey","", "160", "otherstuff100", "baseball", "", "190", "otherstuff5", "lacrosse", "200", "9th June 2018"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I want to insert a row by a condition, new cells "date" on bookends of any date value. There are random numbers of cells of otherstuff between the dates:

```
df.desired <- data.frame(V1=c("stuff","date", "2nd June 2018","date" ,"otherstuff1", "baseball","", "142", "otherstuff2", "football","", "150","date", "4th June 2018","date", "otherstuff99", "hockey","", "160", "otherstuff100", "baseball", "", "190", "otherstuff5", "lacrosse", "200", "date", "9th June 2018","date"), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Comment: Is date formate always like that (ie: day(num) Month (chr) year (num))?

Comment: Yes, but in text string not date format

Comment: The use of a data frame adds unnecessary complexity to the question.  Essentially you are only working with the vector of strings that happens to be part of a data frame.  See these two questions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178451/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-column-is-a-date-in-r and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493969/how-to-insert-elements-into-a-vector)

Answer (score 3):

There are three steps that you need to do:

- find date positions (using `grep`)
- create new data.frame with space for `date` rows
- add `date` to new data.frame

Code:

```
# Find position of `month year`
foo <- grep(paste(month.name, "\\d+$", collapse = "|"), df$V1)
# Expand original data.frame with space for data
dfDesired <- data.frame(x = df$V1[sort(c(1:nrow(df), foo, foo))], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# Find position for date in expanded data.frame
bar <- foo + seq(by = 2, length.out = length(foo))
# Add date
dfDesired$x[c(bar - 1, bar + 1)] <- "date"
```

Notes:

`grep` is done with string: `paste(month.name, "\\d+$", collapse = "|")`

> "January \d+$|February \d+$|March \d+$|April \d+$|May
>   \d+$|June \d+$|July \d+$|August \d+$|September \d+$|October
>   \d+$|November \d+$|December \d+$"

We need `bar` positions as rows in new data.frame are moved by: 1,3,5,+

Comment: but, but, what about `df$V1[3] <- "otherstuff What If We May 666 or March 100"`

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this; it looks like the `dmy` function from `lubridate` package succeeds to recognize all the date formats in your example, but if you have a wider variety of date strings that might not always hold:

```
# lubridate parses your dates in dmy function
df$date_try <- dmy(df$V1) 
# the ones that are not NA must be dates
ind <- c(which(!is.na(df$date_try)))
# insert some bookends at the index locations before and after your dates
new_ind <- c(seq_along(df$date_try), ind + 0.5, ind - 0.5)
new_V1 <- c(df$V1, rep("date", length(ind) * 2))

# currently the bookends are at the end of the list,
# we must re-order them to insert at the proper locations
# create your desired output dataframe
df.new <- data.frame(V1 = new_V1[order(new_ind)])

> head(df.new)
             V1
1         stuff
2          date
3 2nd June 2018
4          date
5   otherstuff1
6      baseball
```