# R: Date Column Containing Non-Date Like Entries

Tags: r, date, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a date column in my dataframe that contains both dates and non-date like entries (e.g. `2<1U+5C0F><U+65F6><U+524D><U+53D1><U+5E03>` and  `2017-11-18` )

How do I go about identifying which rows contain the dates and which contain the characters?

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178451/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-column-is-a-date-in-r/18178539 - so you could do `!is.na(as.Date(df$date, format="%Y-%m-%d"))` if you are able to specify a date format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R you could use `grepl` with `subset`

```
# Sample data
df <- data.frame(
    date = c("2<1U+5C0F><U+65F6><U+524D><U+53D1><U+5E03>", "2017-11-18"))

subset(df, !grepl("U\\+", date))
#        date
#2 2017-11-18
```

This assumes that all non-date entries contain a string `"U+"`.